# Snort pcap_inject not located

Tags: security, snort, ids

I try to experiment the Intrusion Detection System(IDS) using Snort,I installed Snort and WinPcap packages after that I copy the Rules file and paste it to "C:\Snort\rules" next I try to copy the "snort.conf" to "C:\Snort\etc" but it already exists, then I start to execute using **snort -dev i 3** it shows a alert message **The procedure entry point pcap_inject could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Snort\bin\snort.exe.**

Picture of this problem:
[image]

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? Because now I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, winpcap is no longer supported. There is a compatible alternative npcap: https://nmap.org/npcap/#download
When installing npcap, use the latest version (now it's 1.5) and make sure you install npcap with the compatible API option in the installer enabled.
It works fine with Snort 2.9.18.

Answer (score 0):

You should use snortrules_snapshort version same with installed version
Example: Snort_2_9_8_3_Installer.exe with snortrules-snapshot-2983.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

If you are using winpcap then try it using npcap , which you can download from nmap.org

Answer (score 0):

Libpcap originally had no functions that could *transmit* packets.

WinPcap added the `pcap_sendpacket()` function.

OpenBSD added the `pcap_inject()` function.

At some point, *both* of those were added to libpcap, for compatibility with both WinPcap and OpenBSD's libpcap.  They're both supported on Linux/*BSD/Solaris/Windows at minimum.

WinPcap picked up a version of libpcap that had `pcap_inject()`, but this is Windows, where functions in a DLL are *not* made available to users of the DLL by default; they have to be explicitly marked as available (exported).  The WinPcap developers did *not* mark `pcap_inject()` as available, so programs that use it won't work with WinPcap.

Snort apparently chose to use `pcap_inject()` rather than `pcap_sendpacket()`; there's no good reason to choose one or the other.

Libpcap later went with a different scheme for indicating whether a function is available or not; it defaults to "only functions explicitly marked as available are" on both UN*X and windows, and *both* `pcap_inject()` and `pcap_sendpacket()` are marked as available.

Npcap is based on a recent version of libpcap, and thus it makes both `pcap_inject()` and `pcap_sendpacket()` available, so it should work with Snort.